# What is the best way to manage resources in a monad stack like ExceptT a IO?

Tags: haskell, exception, resources, monad-transformers, io-monad

For better or for worse, Haskell's popular [Servant](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/) library has made it common-place to run code in a monad transformer stack involving `ExceptT err IO`. Servant's own handler monad is `ExceptT ServantErr IO`. As many argue, this is a somewhat [troublesome monad](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/exceptions-best-practices-haskell) to work in since there are *multiple ways for failure to unroll*: 1) via normal exceptions from `IO` at the base, or 2) by returning `Left`.

As Ed Kmett's [`exceptions`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) library [helpfully clarifies](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.8.3/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadMask):

> Continuation-based monads, and stacks such as `ErrorT e IO` which provide for multiple failure modes, are invalid instances of this [`MonadMask`] class.

This is very inconvenient since `MonadMask` gives us access the helpful [polymorphic version of] `bracket` function for doing resource management (not leaking resources due to an exception, etc.). But in Servant's `Handler` monad we can't use it.

I'm not very familiar with it, but some people say that the solution is to use `monad-control` and it's many partner libraries like `lifted-base` and `lifted-async` to give your monad access to resource management tools like `bracket` (presumably this works for `ExceptT err IO` and friends as well?).

However, it seems that `monad-control` is [losing favor in the community](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/06/exceptions-transformers), yet I can't tell what the alternative would be. Even Snoyman's recent `safe-exceptions` library uses Kmett's `exceptions` library and avoids `monad-control`.

Can someone clarify the current story for people like me who are trying to plow our way into serious Haskell usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could work in `IO`, return a value of type `IO (Either ServantErr r)` at the end and wrap it in `ExceptT` to make it fit the handler type. This would let you use `bracket` normally in `IO`. One problem with this approach is that you lose the "automatic error management" that `ExceptT` provides. That is, if you fail in the middle of the handler you'll have to perform an explicit pattern match on the `Either` and things like that.

---

The above is basically reimplementing the `MonadTransControl` instance for `ExceptT`, which is

```
instance MonadTransControl (ExceptT e) where
    type StT (ExceptT e) a = Either e a
    liftWith f = ExceptT $ liftM return $ f $ runExceptT
    restoreT = ExceptT
```

*monad-control* works fine when lifting functions like `bracket`, but it has odd corner cases with functions like the following (taken from [this blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/01/monadbasecontrol-is-unsound/)):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control

callTwice :: IO a -> IO a
callTwice action = action >> action

callTwice' :: ExceptT () IO () -> ExceptT () IO ()
callTwice' = liftBaseOp_ callTwice
```

If we pass to `callTwice'` an action that prints something and fails immediately after

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let printAndFail = lift (putStrLn "foo") >> throwE ()
    runExceptT (callTwice' printAndFail) >>= print
```

It prints "foo" two times anyway, even if our intuition says that it should stop after the first execution of the action fails.

---

An alternative approach is to use the [`resourcet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet) library and work in a  `ExceptT ServantErr (ResourceT IO) r` monad. You would need to use `resourcet` functions like [`allocate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.8/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#v:allocate) instead of `bracket`, and adapt the monad at the end like:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

adapt :: ExceptT ServantErr (ResourceT IO) r -> ExceptT err IO r 
adapt = ExceptT . runResourceT . runExceptT
```

or like:

```
import Control.Monad.Morph

adapt' :: ExceptT err (ResourceT IO) r -> ExceptT err IO r 
adapt' = hoist runResourceT
```

Comment: Excellent response! So it seems there isn't really a "standard" way to solve this problem? It makes sense that monad-control has edge cases in this situation since, according to Kmett, it probably can't have a sound implementation for these stacks anyway.

Comment: Is there difference between `ExceptT err (ResourceT IO) r` and `ResourceT (ExceptT err IO) r`. AFAICS the `ResourceT` is simply a reader, so it should commute; but are there some other implications?

Comment: @phadej I believe both orders would work, but I feel that `ExceptT err (ResourceT IO) r` is more natural.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation: have your code live in IO instead of ExceptT, and wrap each handler function in a `ExceptT . try`.

Comment: After much pondering and research I must confess I'm coming to this conclusion, which seems like a cop-out in some ways, but the most clear-cut and pain-free solution.

Comment: Just because it's easier doesn't mean it's wrong. I really think people are making this whole problem more complicated than it needs to be, for nebulous benefits.